Language bar alternative, Win 10
I often need to change the language in a short period of time. The small language bar icon is not very convenient. It would be more convenient to have the name of the current language pop up in large letters all over the screen for a brief moment, or to have the screen flicker briefly in a specific color for each language. Then I don't need to change the focus of my eyes as the whole screen is affected.
A similar question was posted here without answer.
Windows 10 Pro, 22H2
